# Nested routes with optional parameters

Tags: ember.js

I try to route in Ember through a hierarchy, that means I've clubs grouped by regions. Now I want to see on the left side the group titles listed, with all clubs assigned. If the user selects a club then the details should be displayed on the right. How should I divide this in templates and routes? The route should be like this:

```
/clubs        -> Region and clublist on the left
/clubs/3      -> Region and clublist on the left and details on the right
/clubs/3/edit -> Edit
/clubs/new    -> Create a new club
```

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('clubs', function(){
    this.route('new');
    this.resource('club', {path:':id'}, function(){
      this.route('edit');
    });
  });
});
```

Each route/resource should have their own template, here's a simple example

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/AtebAsOS/6/edit